# How to debug unexpected process termination without core dump or errors logged

Tags: c++, ubuntu, segmentation-fault, out-of-memory, terminate

I have a set of multithreaded executables written in C++ being run from the crontab on an Ubuntu machine that primarily fetch and process data from websocket connections. Each of these executables are run in a while loop, such that if an executable terminates, it is run again immediately.

Whenever I run these executables, they tend to run fine for several hours, but then will unexpectedly terminate (all at the same time), at which point the aforementioned while loop causes them to repeatedly start, run for a few seconds, and then terminate unexpectedly, repeating this cycle ad infinitum.

There are no core files generated (even though I have set "ulimit -c unlimited" and built the executables with "-g -ggdb", so they do generate a core file upon segfault). Also, "dmesg" does not show anything indicating this repeated termination/restarting of the executables, and in fact none of the logs in /var/log seem to show anything of note, so I assume they were not killed due to OOM as per my initial guess. There is also plenty of disk space.

How can I debug an issue like this? Is there anywhere else I can look for error messages?

I forgot to mention that there is nothing of note being printed to stdout/stderr either. Also, another weird thing is that if I kill the script containing the while loop corresponding to one of the executables (without touching any of the other while loops) and then run that script manually on the terminal, the corresponding executable seems to run fine without termination, even as the other executables are still continually restarting and terminating instantly.

I believe I've narrowed it down to something related to stdout. When I log the websocket output to stdout, the continual restarting and termination happens. When I remove that logging, the executable doesn't crash anymore.

Oh so when the executable prints the websocket output to stdout, it pipes this output to "taskset -c 0 gzip -c", and apparently those gzips terminated for some reason and I didn't even notice. Any ideas why that might be or how to debug that?

Comment: How are you running the code? In a systemd service? Are you checking the return code of the executable?

Comment: @AlanBirtles It is run from the crontab at the start of every day. And no with regards to the return code, I guess I should check that

Comment: Cron isn't the right way to run long running services

Comment: Do you perhaps end up with two copies of your cron job running and they interfere with each other?

Comment: Maybe force writing a coredump by doing `raise (SIGABRT);` in the `atexit` handler?

Comment: @AlanBirtles No, there are no duplicate unexpected copies running

Comment: @PeterT Ah I wasn't aware of atexit, will look into that

Comment: well it wouldn't reach the atexit handler if it crashed, but since it's not writing a core dump right now, maybe it's exiting "normally". This would only help you find where it's terminating (and maybe to examine the callstacks of other threads)

Comment: Also you could add a delay/sleep at the start of your application if they close too fast, that would give you time to attach a debugger to the program and then step through it to find out what's happening

Comment: @PeterT Hmm I tested it just now, yeah looks like the function I set with atexit is never called

Comment: I think I've narrowed it down to something related to gzip crashing after I pipe the stdout to it, please see my latest edit to the original post

Comment: What are you doing with the output of `gzip`?

Comment: @AlanBirtles The output of gzip is piped to a file

Comment: Is there enough disk space for the output file?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes there is enough disk space

Comment: It's technically piped to "taskset -c 0 gzip -c > $file", not sure if the taskset could be causing any issues (especially if the taskset core is 0 for each of the multiple gzip calls)

Comment: You could try to run gdb in cron and have it run the executable, so that you are constantly running it in a debugger. Alternately, maybe manually attach gdb and wait until it crashes.

Comment: Also, if it does not crash via eg a segfault, you could try to set breakpoints on various functions such as `abort()` or `exit()`.

Comment: @Sedenion Thank you for your suggestion, but I realized that it is an issue with gzip terminating for some reason. Please see the last part of my original post

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to get stderr output of the main while loop to see something that would be hard printed to the console but not logged.

If it is a shell script, append `>output.log 2>&1` at the end of the linux command.

If not, you can tail `/proc/<pid>/fd/1` where `<pid>` is the linux process id

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I forgot to mention I am already logging stdout/stderr and don't see any hints as to what is going wrong. Also, please see my edit in the original post for an additional detail

Answer (score 0):

Bad websocket inputs is crashing your server?

One possible solution u may want to consider a ids like bro(now called zeek https://zeek.org/) to capture all your traffic from your server( u will need to clone traffic on the switch and have record accurate timestamps of your crashes.

Once you have recorded the crash activity consider playing it back by exporting and crafting the packet(you could copy the hex and attach to client socket and just compile). If it crashes again you have a repro to debug.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, I don't think it is related to websocket inputs, because 1) the executables are each connecting to websockets from completely different sources, and 2) I would think that would cause a segfault and hence a core file, but there is no core file generated here

Comment: Can u place a proxy between the executable and websocket and log that with accurate timestamps then like the ids setup play back later for a repro. Only downside on logging on same machine is in case of hacking activity the repro could wipe everything potentially

Comment: I could, but also, when things are in the cyclical restarting and terminating almost right away phase, the executables don't even get to the point where they read in any messages. The termination happens during the period while they are in the middle of connecting to the websocket endpoints. Each executable makes 10-60 connections, and the termination is happening after they've only connected to 1 or sometimes 2 websocket endpoints

Comment: Actually sorry I take back that first statement, even though they have only connected to 1 or 2 websocket endpoints by the time they terminate, some messages have already been processed from those 1 or 2 endpoints (as the executables are multi-threaded). However, I still don't see how any type of websocket input (even if it is "bad") can cause program termination without a segfault